# php file upload not working with jquery Validator

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm using the jquery validator to validate that my form, but it doesn't upload the file properly.

If I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form it uploads the file but 
doesn't grab the form data passed.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? This question is a little short on information. Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: There are no errors in log I seem to remember that multipart doesnt work with the validator

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the problem I changed.

$the_field = $_REQUEST['field']; 
  $the_field = $_FILES['field']['name'];